# How can I ensure changes to my Celery countdown wont break anything?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-unittest

I have a number of celery tasks in my Django application that are currently being tested synchronously using `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER`. However this option means that I can't test that changes to the `countdown` value in `apply_async` won't break anything.

How can I test that nothing else in my application was depending on the longer countdown now that I suspect I no longer need it?

I'm using Django 1.10 and Celery 3.1 with Python 3.5.

Comment: take a look at freezegun?